# Mahout: Why do we convert the input data to sequence files?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have seen a lot of examples in mahout which require the input data to be converted to sequence file.
What is the purpose of this?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are operating on lots of small files, is almost impossible and a waste of resources put them in HDFS as they are, an easier alternative is to create a sequence file and operate on them this way. See this: [The Small Files Problem](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)